# How can I load an image in C++ using SFML library?

Tags: c++, textures, sfml

**How can I load an image in C++ using SFML library?**

I am making a game using C++, and for textures of bonuses I want to upload *.png from directory instead of creating them in *.cpp file. How can I do this using SFML library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```cpp
sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromFile("path/to/myTexture.png")) {
    perror("Couldn't load texture \"myTexture\".");
    return;
}
```

You can then put it on spirte:

```cpp
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(texture);
```

and finally display it:

```cpp
sprite.setPosition(x,y);
window.draw(sprite);
```